# Python: My if statement is not working but I don't get any error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a tic-tac-toe game and the move_base function in my script is not working. I have seen this type of if statement used before and I don't know why the function is not working. There are no errors but the function doesn't update num_word or moves. I do not have a lot of python experience so I do not know what I am doing wrong. I will add more features to the game but I can't because the basic part of it is not working. I have not seen any other place that tells me how to fix this.

```
#tic tac toe game
#global variables
game_over = False

#game script
def game():
    #game variables

    #positions on the board
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
    three = '3'
    four = '4'
    five = '5'
    six = '6'
    seven = '7'
    eight = '8'
    nine = '9'
    positions = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine]

    num_chosen = ''
    #moves in the game
    moves = 0

    #prints board
    def board():
        print(f'{one}|{two}|{three}')
        print(f'{four}|{five}|{six}')
        print(f'{seven}|{eight}|{nine}')

    #how to check who won
    def check_win_base(xo, num1, num2, num3):
        if num1 == xo and num2 == xo and num3 == xo:
            if(xo == 'x'):
                print('x player wins')
                game_over = True
            elif(xo == 'o'):
                print('o player wins')
                game_over = True
    #check_win_base applied to all numbers
    def check_win(xo):
        check_win_base(xo, one, two, three)
        check_win_base(xo, four, five, six)
        check_win_base(xo, seven, eight, nine)
        check_win_base(xo, one, four, seven)
        check_win_base(xo, two, five, eight)
        check_win_base(xo, three, six, nine)
        check_win_base(xo, one, five, nine)
        check_win_base(xo, three, five, seven)

    #checks if game is a draw
    def check_draw():
        if moves == 9:
            print('The game is a draw')
            game_over = True

    #how to pick a square
    def move_base(xo, num_word, num):    
        if num_chosen == num:
            num_word = xo
            moves += 1
    #move_base applied to all numbers
    def move(xo):
        move_base(xo, one, 1)
        move_base(xo, two, 2)
        move_base(xo, three, 3)
        move_base(xo, four, 4)
        move_base(xo, five, 5)
        move_base(xo, six, 6)
        move_base(xo, seven, 7)
        move_base(xo, eight, 8)
        move_base(xo, nine, 9)

    #all the required functions put together
    def turn(xo):
        board()
        print(f'{xo} move')
        num_chosen = int(input())
        move(xo)
        check_win(xo)
        check_draw()

    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')

#checks if game is over or not
if game_over == False:
    game()
else:
    print('Game Over')
```

Comment: I see a lot of issues in the code. Mostly you are defining new variables with the same name as a variable from the outer scope - probably because you think that will change the value in the outer scope but that's not what happens. You are also re-assigning values to argument variables in some cases. That also doesn't do anything - which is probably not what you are assuming happens.

Comment: Even if you have `nonlocal var` for each var modified in each inner function your `move_base()` won't work because it attempts to modify its parameter `num_word` which won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few key points about variables in python

you may read and change global variables, but cannot assign new values to them unless you specify this is a global variable, therefor this does not work

```
def check_draw():
if moves == 9:
    print('The game is a draw')
    game_over = True
```

but this does

```
def check_draw():
global game_over
if moves == 9:
    print('The game is a draw')
    game_over = True
```

simple types like string,int,float are immutable, means you cannot change them, because in a result you get another object. In this example by changing `num_word` and `moves` you actually assign new value which creates local copy of those variables without changing it's global counterpart

```
def move_base(xo, num_word, num):    
        if num_chosen == num:
            num_word = xo
            moves += 1
```

solution to this mess is simple - use mutable objects, like `dict` or `list`, to retain changes

here is example which works (more or less)

```
# tic tac toe game
#global variables
game_over = False

# game script


def game():
    # game variables

    # positions on the board
    positions = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

    d = {
        "one": '1',
        "two": '2',
        "three": '3',
        "four": '4',
        "five": '5',
        "six": '6',
        "seven": '7',
        "eight": '8',
        "nine": '9',
        "num_chosen": "",
        "moves": 0,  # moves in the game
    }

    # prints board
    def board():
        print(f'{d["one"]}|{d["two"]}|{d["three"]}')
        print(f'{d["four"]}|{d["five"]}|{d["six"]}')
        print(f'{d["seven"]}|{d["eight"]}|{d["nine"]}')

    # how to check who won
    def check_win_base(xo, num1, num2, num3):
        global game_over
        if num1 == xo and num2 == xo and num3 == xo:
            if(xo == 'x'):
                print('x player wins')
                game_over = True
            elif(xo == 'o'):
                print('o player wins')
                game_over = True
    # check_win_base applied to all numbers

    def check_win(xo):
        check_win_base(xo, d["one"], d["two"], d["three"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["four"], d["five"], d["six"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["seven"], d["eight"], d["nine"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["one"], d["four"], d["seven"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["two"], d["five"], d["eight"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["three"], d["six"], d["nine"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["one"], d["five"], d["nine"])
        check_win_base(xo, d["three"], d["five"], d["seven"])

    # checks if game is a draw
    def check_draw():
        global game_over
        if d["moves"] == 9:
            print('The game is a draw')
            game_over = True

    # how to pick a square
    def move_base(xo, num_word, num):
        if d["num_chosen"] == num:
            d[num_word] = xo
            d["moves"] += 1
    # move_base applied to all numbers

    def move(xo):
        move_base(xo, "one", 1)
        move_base(xo, "two", 2)
        move_base(xo, "three", 3)
        move_base(xo, "four", 4)
        move_base(xo, "five", 5)
        move_base(xo, "six", 6)
        move_base(xo, "seven", 7)
        move_base(xo, "eight", 8)
        move_base(xo, "nine", 9)

    # all the required functions put together
    def turn(xo):
        board()
        print(f'{xo} move')
        d["num_chosen"] = int(input())
        move(xo)
        check_win(xo)
        check_draw()

    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')
    turn('o')
    turn('x')


# checks if game is over or not
if game_over == False:
    game()
else:
    print('Game Over')
```

Comment: Thank you so muck. I didn't know that using dictionaries is the best way to deal with the problem. I will use this technique in other scripts as well.

Comment: Please keep in mind that code using `global` is considered bad code in most cases. Functions should get everything they need via parameters and return values with `return`.